# Single Facility Problem

Tags: facility-location

[image]

Hi,

Can someone explain to me how this works or refer to any page that tells how the single facility problem works step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Weiszfeld's algorithm for the (weighted) geometric median.  See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

and

https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2023/06/28/geometric-median-sas.html